# Barra de opcion de visual estudio code

Tags: visual

[image]

como aparezco el menu del lado izquierdo,no me funciona con alt o alt+e

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.